# MVC routing is intercepting physical MP3 files

Tags: model-view-controller, iis-7

I have a MVC app with a directory containing a bunch of media, png, mp3, etc...

The png files serve fine, but the mp3 files are getting picked up in MVC routing.

I've changed the document root to a non mvc directory (just pointed to the content directory) and it serves the mp3 fine, so it's not an iis issue, but an mvc routing issue.

so... why is it grabbing the .mp3 extension? I dont have any routes with mp3 in them...

the error thrown is (not helpfully)

```
[ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: key]
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.FindEntry(TKey key) +12673141
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2.ContainsKey(TKey key) +9
StructureMap.Util.Cache`2.get_Item(KEY key) +97
StructureMap.BuildSession.CreateInstance(Type pluginType) +16
Utility.StructureMapControllerFactory.GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType) in c:\xx\Utility\StructureMapControllerFactory.cs:18
System.Web.Mvc.DefaultControllerFactory.CreateController(RequestContext requestContext, String controllerName) +85
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.ProcessRequestInit(HttpContextBase httpContext, IController& controller, IControllerFactory& factory) +280
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass6.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2() +66
System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClassb`1.<ProcessInApplicationTrust>b__a() +19
System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Func`1 func) +161
System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +405
System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +375
```

Comment: Routes ignore extensions.  You have a route that matches that path

Comment: That's not it, if I change the extension to .txt it serves the file fine, so it's definitely extension related. I have this project running on another server without issue, so... I dont know why its being intercepted here..

Comment: and here's where i realize the config on this instance actually had a rewrite rule for mp3 in place.. nm...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

and here's where i realize the config on this instance actually had a rewrite rule for mp3 in place.. nm...